# Convert decimal mark when reading numbers as input

Tags: python, locale, decimal-point

I have a CSV file with data reading that I want to read into Python. I get lists that contain strings like `"2,5"`. Now doing `float("2,5")` does not work, because it has the wrong decimal mark.

How do I read this into Python as `2.5`?

Comment: did you check : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Babel/0.9.6

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`float("2,5".replace(',', '.'))` will do in most cases

If `value`is a large number and `.`has been used for thousands, you can:

Replace all commas for points: `value.replace(",", ".")`

Remove all but the last point: `value.replace(".", "", value.count(".") -1)`

Comment: Just curious, is it the true-way solution? Looks awful for me.

Comment: @loki2302 - Standard decimal delimiter is a point. If you use anything else (i.e. comma or something more "exotic" like space, a letter or anything else), then you have to replace it to make `float()` understand what you mean.

Comment: The decimal delimiter is a [localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_point#Hindu-Arabic_numeral_system) issue, so I guess @loki2302 wonders if there is a way to inform python to _adhere_ to the localized way of representing a floating-point number when parsing.

Comment: It's not a worldwide *standard*. For instance, in Russia commas are standard and points are not widely used. So, I believe, that correct solution for this problem is to somehow be aware of this document's author locale. Another question is - *since we're talking about CSV, how did they manage to save floats with commas? :-)*. 3,14 is, I believe, 2 integers and not a float.

Comment: @loki2302 Standard csv format for countries with comma as decimal delimiter [is to use `;` as field delimiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) in csv files.

Comment: Standard delimiter is a comma. Everyone knows that, except Americans and English :D

Comment: It was a danish csv-file, and here the comma is standard decimal delimiter. And indeed, the field delimiter was ";".

Comment: @loki2302 Well, you can have CSV-fields with commas even if the delimiter is also a comma. You just need string quoting. Then there's a ton of ways of string quoting in CSV (how to escape the quote? double quotes? backslash?).

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that in germany we sometimes do something like "1,000,024,00" - i know it's not good. But i often have to handle this kind of data. If you don't want to use locale, you can just do it this way:

    `value = "1,000,024,00"
    value = value.replace(",", ".")
    value.replace(".", "", (value.count(".")-1))`

Comment: @Kheldar ... and Australians, and Bangladeshis, and Canadians, and Dominicans, and Egyptians, [and...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett which are all British Commonwealth system users. Point stands.

Comment: @Kheldar I guess... in a circular logic kind of way.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I suppose I haven't been clear enough. My point was simply that delimiters depend on the language you use, mainly how numbers have been represented historically. English-based languages and Latin-based languages use incompatible systems, which is why the UK and former colonies are featured in your list. Regards!

Comment: @Kheldar That is accurate, though I find that point difficult to parse from your original comment.

Answer (score 67):

You may do it the locale-aware way:

```
import locale

# Set to users preferred locale:
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
# Or a specific locale:
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "en_DK.UTF-8")

print locale.atof("3,14")
```

Read [this](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats) section before using this method.

Comment: One should also keep in mind that this won't be thread safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186327/thread-safe-locale-techniques

Answer (score 29):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) supports this out of the box:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', decimal=',')
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Is there some ready command to replace comma decimal points with dot decimal points in pandas (without brute-force replacing with some regex)?

Comment: Didn't find one. But what's wrong with replacing it via apply or applymap?

Comment: If you end up here and try to apply the same logic to `read_html`, if you won't replace also the `thousands` value, you may get parsing errors, as it defaults to the comma if unspecified.    
`df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', decimal=',', thousands='.')
`

Answer (score 8):

using a regex  will be more reliable

```
import re

decmark_reg = re.compile('(?<=\d),(?=\d)')

ss = 'abc , 2,5 def ,5,88 or (2,5, 8,12, 8945,3 )'

print ss
print decmark_reg.sub('.',ss)
```

result

```
abc , 2,5 def ,5,88 or (2,5, 8,12, 8945,3 )
abc , 2.5 def ,5.88 or (2.5, 8.12, 8945.3 )
```

If you want to treat more complex cases (numbers with no digit before the decimal mark for exemple) the regex I crafted to detect all types of numbers in the following thread may be of interest for you:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text/5929469](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text/5929469#5929469)

Comment: How can you do this on a pandas dataframe (not string)?

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing all the decimal commas with decimal dots:

```
float_as_str = "2,5"
float_as_str = float_as_str.replace(",", ".");
some_float = float(float_as_str)
```

The function `replace`, of course, work on any substring as python does now differentiate between char and string.

Comment: `str` is a bad, bad variable name.

Comment: you are right, I just copied the code from some tutorial page and added the last line...

Comment: `floatAsStr` is not really much better. :-P

Answer (score 4):

First **you must ensure what locale was used to provide the number**. Failing to do this random problems surely will occur.

```
import locale

loc = locale.getlocale()  # get and save current locale
# use locale that provided the number;
# example if German locale was used:
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
pythonnumber = locale.atof(value)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)  # restore saved locale
```

Comment: As a warning, let me cite the docs here:

```
It is generally a bad idea to call setlocale() in some library routine, since as a side effect it affects the entire program. Saving and restoring it is almost as bad: it is expensive and affects other threads that happen to run before the settings have been restored.
```

Answer (score 4):

if dots are used as thousand separators, to swap commas and dots you could use a third symbol as temporary placeholder like so:

```
value.replace('.', '#').replace(',', '.').replace('#', ',')
```

but seeing as you want to convert to float from string, you could just remove any dots and then replace any commas with dots

```
float(value.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))
```

IMO this is the most readable solution

Answer (score 1):

I have an application (not under my control) in which the incoming monetary value can be in any of the two formats, at least while we convince the customer to change this. There is ambiguity when a single separator is provided: 1,039 can mean 1.036 or 1036 (thousand and ...) but in practice since it is money that is represented, over 2 characters behind the separator are assumed to be not-decimals.

Below is this code:

```
def tolerant_monetary_float (x, max_decimals = 2):

    num_dot = x.count ('.')
    num_com = x.count (',')
    
    if not num_dot:
        # no dot
        if not num_com:
            # no dot, no comma
            return float (x)

        if num_com > 1:
            # more than one comma
            return float (x.replace (',', ''))

        # 1 comma: its ambiguous: 1,000 can mean 1000 or 1.0
        if len (x) - x.find (',') -1 <= max_decimals:
            # assume the comma is decimal separator
            return float (x.replace (',', '.'))

        # assume comma is thousand separator
        return float (x.replace (',', ''))

    if not num_com:
        # no comma 
        if not num_dot:
            # no dot, no comma
            return float (x)

        if num_dot > 1:
            # more than one dot
            return float (x.replace ('.', ''))

        # 1 dot: its ambiguous: 1.000 can mean 1000 or 1.0
        if len (x) - x.find ('.') -1 <= max_decimals:
            # assume the dot is decimal separator
            return float (x)

        # assume dot is thousand separator
        return float (x.replace ('.', ''))

    # mix of dots and commas
    if num_dot > 1 and num_com > 1:
        return ValueError (f'decimal number cannot have a mix of "," and ".": {x}')

    ix_dot = x.find ('.') 
    ix_com = x.find (',')

    if ix_dot < ix_com:
        # dot is before comma: 1.000,35
        return float (x.replace ('.', '').replace (',', '.'))

    # comma is before dot: 1,000.35
    return float (x.replace (',', ''))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1') == 1.0)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1.2345') == 12345.0)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1.234') == 1234.0)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1.23') == 1.23)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1.2') == 1.2)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1,2345') == 12345.0)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1,234') == 1234.0)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1,23') == 1.23)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1,2') == 1.2)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1234,5') == 1234.5)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1.234,5') == 1234.5)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1,234.5') == 1234.5)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1,234,567.85') == 1234567.85)
    assert (tolerant_monetary_float ('1.234.567,85') == 1234567.85)
```