# Float number in Gtk Treestore: i18n of decimal comma/point

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

Can anybody tell me why this example doesn't work when I try to add a float in one of the columns?

It produces a type error (**TypeError: Must be number, not str**) in the line at the bottom (**self.liststore[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSHBj.png) = number**).

[image]

**Edit**: I narrowed it down. My operating system displays the float with a comma (3,2) for the decimals, but python uses a dot (3.2) for decimals. Is there an easy solution within the code, that allows the program to work on either operating system setting?

```
    from gi.repository import Gtk

    class CellRendererTextWindow(Gtk.Window):

        def __init__(self):
            Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="CellRendererText Example")

            self.set_default_size(200, 200)

            self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, float)
            self.liststore.append(["Measurement 1", 3.2])
            self.liststore.append(["Measurement 2", 2.0])
            self.liststore.append(["Measurement 3", 4.75])

            treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)

            renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Text", renderer_text, text=0)
            treeview.append_column(column_text)

            floatrenderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            floatrenderer.set_property("editable", True)

            column_editabletext = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Value",
                floatrenderer, text=1)
            treeview.append_column(column_editabletext)

            floatrenderer.connect("edited", self.text_edited)

            self.add(treeview)

        def text_edited(self, widget, path, number):
            self.liststore[path][1] = number

    win = CellRendererTextWindow()
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Original example from: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cellrenderers.html#cellrenderertext

Comment: the supposedly "duplicate" does not have any clue on using a float in a CellRendererText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it:

[convert decimal mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106417/convert-decimal-mark)

use:

```
      float("2,5".replace(',', '.'))
```

or in my case:

```
      float(number.replace(',', '.'))
```