# Sorting list of tuples containing numbers as strings

Tags: python, sorting

I'm new to programming and I'm not sure how to do this correctly. I'm trying to sort a list of tuples such as below by the second value and I need them to be sorted as if they were ints:

```
    [u'value3', '5,423']
    [u'value', '1,389']
    [u'value1', '3,385']
    [u'anothervalue', '2,789']
    [u'value2', '430']
```

Right now I have this:

```
    sortedList= sorted(listToSort, key=lambda x: (x[1]))
```

as the result I get this:

```
    [u'value', '1,389']
    [u'anothervalue', '2,789']
    [u'value1', '3,385']
    [u'value2', '430']
    [u'value3', '5,423']
```

but I need it to be more like:

```
    [u'value3', '5,423']
    [u'value1', '3,385']
    [u'anothervalue', '2,789']
    [u'value', '1,389']
    [u'value2', '430']
```

or in ascending order, it doesn't matter.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: side comment: these are lists, not tuples :)

Comment: `key=lambda x: int(x[1])` should do the trick

Comment: Is the comma a decimal comma or a thousand delimiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the following:

```
sortedList = sorted(listToSort, key=lambda x: int(x[1].replace(',', '')), reverse=True)
```

**EDIT:** original answer did descending, edited to be ascending

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: If it works, you should use `int` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 0):

If your values are integers with comma as thousands delimiter, you should do:

```
sortedList = sorted(listToSort, key=lambda x: int(x[1].replace(",", "")))
```

If your values are float:

```
sortedList = sorted(listToSort, key=lambda x: float(x[1].replace(",", ".")))
```

Or you can set right locale to not use `replace`:

[convert decimal mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106417/convert-decimal-mark)

Comment: you cant just do this because of the commas. you can do `float(x[1].replace(',','') to get rid of commas

Comment: also, sorted has a 4th parameter `reverse` which can be set so it sorts in reverse order.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that there are commas in values.

Comment: i think you meant to replace with blanks, not periods. that would give decimal values for large values, and `ValueError` if the value has more than one comma (ie, `1,000,000`)

Comment: @RNar Well, for [some people](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) it makes sense to consider the comma as the decimal mark.

Comment: this is true, but look at the question, it seems it should be taken in as a blank instead as the OP seems to want to organize from largest to smallest and the bigger numbers have the commas. but yes, i see what you mean