# error performing np.std for array

Tags: numpy, python-3.5

this is my code, im trying to calculate the standard deviation of an imported list which is shown below

```
 b=[]
    #time=[]

with open('nt.txt') as csvfile:
    data=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=('\t'))
    index=0
    for line in data:
            b.append(line[1])
            #out=line[0]
            #new=out.split(" ")
            #b.append(new[0])
        #else:break


   x=statistics.stdev(b)
print(x)
```

with b =`['-0,002549', '-0,002040', '-0,001530']`  as my output

i get ...

```
    raise TypeError(msg.format(type(x).__name__)) from None

TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator
```

Comment: I suspect it is the comma being used for the decimal separator

Comment: how can i solve this ....

Comment: I don't have data to test with, but this link provides one possible solution https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2013-July/034840.html

Comment: i have improved the code .... i think.... now i would like to calculate the standard deviation but get the error as descbribed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
results=np.array([[x],[b]]).astype(np.float32)
```

You have to set the type of the numpy `array`, not the `list`.

Comment: with that done i get this...     results=np.array([[x],[b]]).astype(dtype='float64')

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-0,002549'

Comment: That's because you're using commas instead of periods as decimal points. You can correct that using this suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106417/convert-decimal-mark

Comment: Please consider upvoting this response.