# Python: extract number from String

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I was trying to get a "price tag String" to get converted into a float, so I can easily compare the result with other prices.
I searched for 2 hours for a answer for this "simple problem", but none of them fitted my needs.

So basically, I have a price like this:

```
1.222.333,44 EUR
```

(comma and period swapped because I live in Germany, which is also pretty annoying)

And I want to get this for easy comparing:

```
1222333.44
```

The main idea is to compare prices, which is my school project.
I used to do everything with php, which worked, but was way too slow.

If you have a more elegant or simple way, please let me know.

Comment: More elegant than what? You didn't post a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert decimal mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106417/convert-decimal-mark)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This work for the specific case you provided:

```
float(s.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.').split(' ')[0])
```

It requires:

1. Periods in price are only separators;
2. Only one comma in price and is just a decimal mark;
3. The price comes first and is separated from other strings by a whitespace.

Just to mention in case people need more generalized solution, [hiro protagonist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487462/python-extract-number-from-string/44487500#44487520) using `locale` is very helpful when you need a simple way to switch between numeral systems during coding or when maintaining your codes.

Answer (score 8):

you can use your (or any) [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) to convert a [string to a float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.atof):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
print(locale.atof('1.222.333,44'))  # -> 1222333.44
```

depending on your default locale you may not even have to specify the locale.

in your case you may need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the currency (EUR) part away:

```
price = '1.222.333,44 EUR'
price_float = locale.atof(price.split()[0])
print(price_float) # -> 1222333.44
```

note: it may be enough not to set`LC_ALL` but just `LC_NUMERIC` to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

**If your string is "1.222.333,44 EUR"**

```
prince = "1.222.333,44 EUR"
price = price[:-4]
price = price.replace(".","").replace(",",".")
floatprice = float(price)
```

**If it is just like this "1.222.333,44"**

```
floatprice = float("1.222.333,44".replace(".","").replace(",","."))
```