# Insert comma to numbers in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

```
Evaluate Issuance Fee for Weekly Cycle
    [Documentation]    This keyword evaluates the FIRST Projected Cycle Due on a 'Weekly' cycle.
    [Arguments]    ${PrincipalAmount}    ${Rate}    ${RateBasis}
    ${Time}    Set Variable    7
    ${Time}    Convert To Integer    ${Time}
    ${ProjectedCycleDue}    Evaluate    (((${PrincipalAmount})*(${Rate}))*(${Time}))/${RateBasis}
    ${ProjectedCycleDue}    Convert To Number    ${ProjectedCycleDue}    2
    [Return]    ${ProjectedCycleDue}
```

The keyword returned a number with the format "1500.00".
Is there a way in robot framework where we can format the number to have a comma?

Comment: Where do you want the command? Or are you asking how to use a comma instead of a decimal point?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before return

```
${ProjectedCycleDue}=    Replace String    ${ProjectedCycleDue}    .    ,
```

Similar problem below; Since robot is python wrapper the solution could be the same.

[convert decimal mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106417/convert-decimal-mark)