# Sort a list according two items inside tuples- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I will appreciate some help to fix my code and take the right results.

Let's say that my lists(tuple inside a list) may have that 3 outputs for example:

```
list1 = [('a', 3.30, '' ,'' ), ('b', 3.20, '' , '' ), ......]

list2 = [('a', 3.30, 2.90, '' ), ('b', 3.20, 2.95, '' ), ........]

list3 = [('a', 3.30, 2.90, '' ), ('b', 3.20, '' , ''), ........]
```

My lists always have a price in [1] place and sometimes have in [2] place.
I want to sort my list according all that prices.
My code below works good for example list1 and example list2.

```
from operator import itemgetter
sort_list = sorted(list, key=itemgetter(1))
sort_list = sorted(sort_list, key=itemgetter(2))
print(sort_list)
```

But for `list3` doesn't work well, because it recognize the empty cell of [2] and it shorted first.
I would like to ignore the price of an empty cell, if there is. So the print output for `list3` should be

`('a', 3.30, 2.90, '' ), ('b', 3.20, '' , '')`.

Because, `2.90 < 3.20` and I ignore the empty space

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to represent `2.90` with `2,90` in your tuples?  That won't work because the two values will be parsed as separate entries in the tuple.

Comment: Please fix your numbers - use a `.` for decimals. If you got multiple prices inside one tuple, which one should be used to sort - the first? the second? the lower / higher one?

Comment: the function you have does not work for the lists you have since the `[2]` for both list one and two is 30 for the first element and 20 for the second element

Comment: In your example, you seem to want to compare the *second* price of the `a` `tuple` (`2.90`) to the *first* price of the `b` `tuple`. That's confusing at best; the normal assumption would be that you'd compare `3.30` to `3.20` and ignore the `2.90`. Is that really what you want? No built-in will do this for you; you'd need to write your own `key` function.

Comment: Your sort does not make sense. Why does `2.90 < 3.20` matter? You never compare element 1 with element 2. The way it is now, you sort primarily by element 2, and in case of ties by element 1. Maybe you want to sort by the `min`, `max`, `sum` or `avg` of those two numbers instead?

Comment: @mpantogi: That makes `a` and `b` each a `tuple` of two `int`s, not individual `float`s. Python uses the American/British (and for that matter, C) approach to decimal values, you can't use commas for the decimal point.

Comment: Here is how it looks, inside the tuple there is variables and i don't get any issue according the ',' character:
a = 'example '    b = 3,30   c = 2,90
my_tuple = a, b, c
list.append(my_tuple)

Comment: @mpantogi: That doesn't use `float`s at all. The `tuple` it creates has the value: `('example', (3, 30), (2, 90))`. If you're consistent, that will perform a comparison that kinda works, in that the `tuple`s compare lexicographically, so the first element (the integer component) is compared first, and the second element (the fractional component) is compared second. But if you make a mistake, and don't pad to two decimal places on the fractional component (so in one place you use `b = 3,3` and in another you use `b = 3,20`), you'll get "mysteriously" incorrect sorting.

Comment: @ShadowRanger So it compares it lexicographically, never thought that.Really, my print gives me :(example', '3,90',' 2,90').Finally, my results will use 'commas',so should be a solution1: to let it compare lexicographically and ignore the empty cell or solution2: change ',' to '.' and use min to sorted acording elements in place [1] and [2] and then when  i write it to csv change again '.' to ','.Please advise

Comment: @mpantogi: Sadly, there [does not appear to be any built-in support in the `csv` module for converting `.` to `,` and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7106417/364696). The usual solution is to work with the logical types, then convert (e.g. with formatting operators) as you're outputting. For example, you could convert a `float` known to have two decimal places of precision (rounding if it's a little off) to a Euro-style decimal format with `'{:.2f}'.format(123.4).replace('.', ',')`, which creates the string `'123,40'`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering problem as written:

Use a `key` function of `lambda tup: [x for x in tup[2:0:-1] if not isinstance(x, str)]`. Don't bother to sort twice, this sorts on both values at once in a single pass:

```
list3 = [('a', 3.30, 2.90, '' ), ('b', 3.20, '' , '')]
sort_list = sorted(list3 , key=lambda tup: [x for x in tup[2:0:-1] if not isinstance(x, str)])
print(sort_list)
```

which outputs:

```
[('a', 3.3, 2.9, ''), ('b', 3.2, '', '')]
```

To example the `key` function here, it slices out indexes 2 and 1, in that order. When one of them is a `str`, it omits it, otherwise it keeps it as part of the key. So `('a', 3.3, 2.9, '')` produces a `key` value of `[2.9, 3.3]`, while `('b', 3.2, '', '')` produces a `key` value of `[3.2]` alone.

I'll warn you that this will confuse anyone maintaining your code; in normal code, you compare position n to position n unconditionally, you don't have cases where position n doesn't exist in one element, causing you instead compare position n to position n-1 in the other element.

Also note that Python doesn't allow you to use commas for the decimal point; if the desired value is three and two tenths, the literal you want is `3.20` (or equivalently, `3.2`), not `3,20` (which is *not* equivalent to `3,2`); the former is the numeric value intended, the latter is a `tuple` of two `int`s (`3` and `20` as unrelated values). You might think `3,20` works, but only because you zero padded your fractional component, so when comparing the `tuple`s it compares the integer component first, then the fractional component (which, thanks to being padded, compares correctly). If you ever compared `3,3` to `3,20` though, you'd get incorrect sorting, because while `3.3` is greater than `3.20` (the trailing zero is irrelevant), `3,3` is less than `3,20` (because the `3`s are equal, and `20` is greater than `3`). If decimal level precision is needed, use the `decimal.Decimal` type, but if this is toy code, use `float`; using a `tuple` of two `int`s is typically more error prone than either of the other options.

Comment: That's great. To avoid the confuse should it better to give the variable inside the tuple x = None , when  my soup doesn't find a price?Because until now i tell it x = '', if doesn't find a price.Thank you

Comment: @mpantogi: `None` is slightly easier to filter out, so it's not a bad idea if there isn't a cleaner solution. It would help to know the *meaning* of these prices; it might make sense to use a filler value identical to the single known value, or use `math.inf` or `-math.inf` as a filler in index `1` (with the sole known price in index `2`), which would let you use `operator.itemgetter(2, 1)` as the `key` for a single round sort step without the complication of a highly custom `lambda` for `key`s.