# How to convert strings of decimal values ​from excel to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

The system of notation of decimal numbers in the Excel files I am dealing with is (I think) the European system (like French and German). So I have numbers like:

- '23,4588'
- '78,056888'

Note that they are in the form of strings. When I try to convert them to float python raises an exception:

```
>>> float('78,056888')
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '78,056888'
```

Here's how I solve the problem:

```
 try:
     decim = int(excel_value)
 except ValueError:
     remap = {ord(','): '.'}
     decim = float(excel_value.translate(remap))
```

It seems to work as I want.

So my question is: is there a more appropriate python method for solving these kinds of problems?

Comment: this one looks interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7106835/11610186 (and the one below, in case if you specifically deal with ```pandas```)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this more succinctly with `str.replace`:

```py
decim = float(excel_value.replace(',', '.'))
```

Comment: This throws an error. You forgot a closing parenthesis at the end.

Comment: You're right, thanks