# How to convert str into float? ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,25691372'

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, spyder, xgboost

I'm using XGBoost for feature importance, I want to select the features that give me the 90 % of importance, so at first I build a Dataframe beacause I need it for excel and then I write a while cycle to evalutate the features that give me 90% of importances. After this there is a neural network (but it isn't in the code below). I know that maybe there are some easiest way to do this but it gives me an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,25691372'
```

The code is

```
  import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn import preprocessing

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


dataset = pd.read_csv('CompleteDataSet_original_Clean_CONC.csv', decimal=',', delimiter = ";")
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

label = dataset.iloc[:,-1]
features = dataset.drop(columns = ['Label'])
y_max_pre_normalize = max(label)
y_min_pre_normalize = min(label)

def denormalize(y):
    final_value = y*(y_max_pre_normalize-y_min_pre_normalize)+y_min_pre_normalize
    return final_value
X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(features, label, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 1, shuffle = True)

y_test2 = y_test1.to_frame()
y_train2 = y_train1.to_frame()

scaler1 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler2 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler1.fit_transform(X_train1)
X_test = scaler2.fit_transform(X_test1)


scaler3 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler4 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
y_train = scaler3.fit_transform(y_train2)
y_test = scaler4.fit_transform(y_test2)


sel = XGBRegressor(colsample_bytree= 0.7, learning_rate = 0.005, max_depth = 5, min_child_weight = 3, n_estimators = 1000)
sel.fit(X_train, y_train)
importances = sel.feature_importances_

importances = [str(i) for i in importances]

importances = [i.replace(".", ",") for i in importances]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(features.columns)
df1.columns = ['Features']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(importances)
df2.columns = ['Importances [%]']
result = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis = 1)
result = result.sort_values(by='Importances [%]', ascending=False)

result.to_excel("Feature_Results.xlsx") 

i = 0
somma = 0
feature = []
while somma <=0.9:
    a = result.iloc[i,-1]
    somma = float(a) + somma
    feature.append(result.iloc[i,-2])
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Replace the `,` with a `.`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7106417/1324033

Comment: I've only skimmed the code, but it seems like `str(i).replace(".", ",") for i in importances` is the root of the problem. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Yes, the problem is this. I did it because I need to export this dataframe into excel. So I prefere to have the "," as decimal separator

Comment: Right, Excel is locale-specific. I see that now, `result.to_excel()`

Comment: @wjandrea I simply delete the two line where I use .replace and it works. But how can I change the dot in a comma without re-doing the DataFrameafter the while cycle?

Comment: Is there a smarter way to do what I do in the while cycle?

Comment: As an aside, why do you assign column names after creating DataFrames? It doesn't make much sense to me to do `df1 = pd.DataFrame(features.columns); df1.columns = ['Features']` instead of `df_1 = pd.DataFrame(features.columns, columns=['Features'])`. Same thing with the two different list comprehensions to for `importances,` that should be trivial to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`locale.atof()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html#locale.atof) to handle `,` being used as the decimal separator.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')
...
    somma = locale.atof(a) + somma
```

Comment: And the reason for using atof is that the decimal separator depends on the locale - and the printed version given in the question is for a locale that uses `,` instead of `.` - and python can't parse that directly when calling `float` - as it expects `.` instead.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. The error is Error: unsupported locale setting.  How can I fix it?

Comment: You probably don't have the locale installed in your machine. You can check with `locale -a` and install it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting/37112094

Comment: @GabrieleValvo fr_FR is just one possible choice. Use whatever locale you're using, whether that's it_IT (Italian), de_DE (German), de_CH (Swiss German)...

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to install it. I have to use the prompt?

Comment: It depends on your OS.

Comment: I'm using Zorin

Comment: Zorin is based on Ubuntu. Check out this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server

Answer (score 3):

```py
float('0,25691372'.replace(",", "."))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert "0,0001" into  "0.0001" and then convert the string to float.