# How to replace characters in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm doing some measurements in the lab and want to transform them into some nice Python plots. The problem is the way the software exports CSV files, as I can't find a way to properly read the numbers. It looks like this:

```
-10;-0,0000026  
-8;-0,00000139  
-6;-0,000000546   
-4;-0,000000112  
-2;-5,11E-09  
0,0000048;6,21E-09  
2;0,000000318  
4;0,00000304  
6;0,0000129  
8;0,0000724  
10;0,000268
```

Separation by `;` is fine, but I need every `,` to be `.`.
Ideally I would like Python to be able to read numbers such as `6.21E-09` as well, but I should be able to fix that in excel...

My main issue: Change every `,` to `.` so Python can read them as a float.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34315381/812912

Comment: You should be able to set the sepration when you export in excel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert decimal mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106417/convert-decimal-mark)

Comment: `float` already understand the cientific notation, so you only need to replace `,` by `.` and then use the `float` function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be for you to convert them to string and then use the `.replace()` method to pretty much do anything. For i.e.

```
txt = "0,0000048;6,21E-09"
txt = txt.replace(';', '.')
```

You could also read the CSV file (I don't know how you are reading the file) but depending on the library, you could change the 'delimiter' (to `:` for example). CSV is Comma-separated values and as the name implies, it separates columns by means of `'`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a simple way to fix my problems. My issue is no more!

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want in Python, for example:

```py
import csv

with open('path_to_csv_file', 'r') as csv_file:
    data = list(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';'))

data = [(int(raw_row[0]), float(raw_row[1].replace(',', '.'))) for row in data]

with open('path_to_csv_file', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: I edited to make it a one-liner, using int for the first column to prevent the 2.0 notation and float with the replacement of `,` by `.` for the second column.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped! My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider a regex to match the ','  all in the text, then loop the match results in a process that takes ',' to '.'.