# How to print a price with commas in python?

Tags: python

I have float 12.200000 and I need to use string formatting to output 12,20. How do I do that?
I am total begginer and I can't figure it out from the docs.

Comment: I found this to be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators

Comment: @KennethGithambo, that's for the thousandths separator. OP wants a comma instead of a dot to separate the decimal part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106417/convert-decimal-mark

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```py
flt = 12.200000
flt = str(flt)

if len(flt) == 4:
    flt += "0"
print(flt.replace(".", ","))
```

What this does, is first turn the `float` into a `string`. Then, we check if the length of the string is 4. If it is 4, we add a zero at the end. Finally, at the end, we replace the `.` into a `,`. This gives the desired output of `12,20`.

Answer (score 1):

If your value is a float than you can simply cast it to string and use the replace() method.

```
value = 12.200000
output = str(value).replace(".", ",")
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use round to ge the float to first two decimal places. To replace the . with a , you need to convert the float to a string and use flt.replace('.',',') to get the desired answer. Convert it back to a float data type.

```
flt = 12.200000
flt = round(flt,2)
flt = str(flt) 
flt.replace('.',',') # Replace . with ,
float(flt)  # 12,20
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
float = str(float)
#this converts the float to a string

float = float.replace(".", ",")
#this replaces the point with a comma

if len(float) == 4:
  float += "0"
#this checks whether the float should end with a zero, and if it does it adds it
```